# Recursive View Message - Azure Data Bricks

Tags: sql, pyspark, azure-databricks

**Error :**

AnalysisException: Recursive view `management_db`.`v_extract` detected (cycle: `management_db`.`v_extract` -> `management_db`.`v_extract`)

Query outisde of the view works , but putting query in view fails with error above .

Any ideas on how to resolve this error ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW management_db.v_FINAL_EXTRACT as

select
  A.*,
  B.CURRENCY,
  B.X_REVENUE_TOTAL,
  B.Y_REVENUE_TOTAL
 
from
  (
    SELECT
      A.CUSTOMER,
      A.AGREEMENT,
      A.SOURCEKEY,
      COUNT(A.CURRENCY) AS NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES_PRESENT
    From
      management_db.v_EXTRACT A
    group by
      CUSTOMER,
      AGREEMENTN,
      SOURCEKEY
    having
      COUNT(CURRENCY) > 1
  ) As A
  left outer join management_db.v_EXTRACT B on A.SOURCEKEY = B.SOURCEKEY
```

Comment: How can it work to query from management_db.v_EXTRACT which has not yet been created?  Can you share a query you use outisde of the view?

Comment: Sorry typo. View to be created has a different name.

Comment: select
  A.*,
  B.CURRENCY,
  B.X_REVENUE_TOTAL,
  B.Y_REVENUE_TOTAL
 
from
  (
    SELECT
      A.CUSTOMER,
      A.AGREEMENT,
      A.SOURCEKEY,
      COUNT(A.CURRENCY) AS NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES_PRESENT
    From
      management_db.v_EXTRACT A
    group by
      CUSTOMER,
      AGREEMENTN,
      SOURCEKEY
    having
      COUNT(CURRENCY) > 1
  ) As A
  left outer join management_db.v_EXTRACT B on A.SOURCEKEY = B.SOURCEKEY

Answer (score 0):

Works now . Mysterious.
Works now . Mysterious.
Works now . Mysterious